# Mockito: mock constructor isn't called

Tags: java, apache-spark, mockito

I'm trying test a Java spark application with Mockito. What I want to do is mock the constructor of MineDataFrame object so that when method datesAvg is called, it return a given object. But when I run the test, real method is called instead of mock method.
I'm using mockito 3.7.7.
Here the code of Test:

```
    @Test
    public void mainTest(){

        String[] str = new String[2];
        str[0] = "tospark";
        str[1] = "4";
        List<MineData1> list = new ArrayList<MineData1>();

        MineDataFrame returned;

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("MineData")
                .setMaster("local[3]")
                .set("es.nodes", *address*)
                .set("es.port", "9200")
                .set("es.nodes.discovery", "false")
                .set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true");

        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf).getOrCreate();

        SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(sc.conf());

          ***filling of list ***

        Dataset<MineData1> ds = spark.createDataset(list, Encoders.bean(MineData1.class));
        MineDataFrame mineDataFrame = new MineDataFrame(ds);

        try (MockedConstruction<MineDataFrame> mocked = Mockito.mockConstruction(MineDataFrame.class,
                (mock,context) -> {
                    when(mock.datesAvg(Mockito.any(SparkSession.class))).thenReturn(mineDataFrame);
                    
        })) {
                    DataProcessing3.main(str);
                    returned = DataProcessing3.getAvgMineTime();
                    assertEquals(mineDataFrame,returned);
       }
    }
```

...and a piece of code of main:

```
       MineDataFrame avg_miners = new MineDataFrame(mineDataTable);
       avgMineTime = avg_miners.datesAvg(spark);
       System.out.println("avgMineTime:");
       avgMineTime.print();
```

Any suggestion to resolve the problem?
Help please

Comment: Your code is really hard to read but it doesn't look there's anything wrong. Is it possible that `datesAvg` is defined as a `static` method?

Comment: Also what is the error you see? It can be a problem of wrong implementation of `equals` in `MineDataFrame`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert. datesAvg isn't a static method. Last line of code of main reported above should print mineDataFrame created in test, but it print an empty dataset, so assert return an error.

Comment: There's no equals method implemented in MineDataFrame. Should there be?

Comment: If there's no `equals`, then `Object`'s will be called, that should be fine. Looks really odd, what you can do is try debugging each statement and see the state of `avgMineTime` in your class throughout the execution. Suggestion: I don't know how much control you have over those classes, but if you can avoid using static methods that keep state is static fields, those methods are really hard to test. And for constructors try supplying any dependencies instead of using `new`

Comment: Thanks, but... what do you mean when you say "try suppluing any dependencies instead of using new"?

Comment: I mean that if you change `DataProcessing3.main(str)` to `DataProcessing3.main(str, new MineDataFrame(...))` then you can easily mock that MineDataFrame instead of using `mockConstruction`. Google for what Inversion of Control is to get an idea.